# Performance of SQL standards vs T-SQL extensions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, query-performance, ansi-sql

Articles on the internet say user-defined functions can either burden or increase the performance.

Now, I know that standard SQL is pretty limited, however, some of the behavior can still be written as in T-SQL built-in functions.

For example, `adddays()` vs. `dateadd()` . Another point I've heard that its also better to use `coalesce()` - the ANSI standard function rather than `isNull()`.

What is the performance difference between using the ANSI SQL standard functions vs T-SQL functions?

Does T-SQL adds any burden what so ever on the performance with it trying to make the job easier, or not?

My research does not seem to indicate a trend.

Comment: Built in functions are better than UDF functions but when not properly used they can still cause major performance issues. For example when using them in a where clause. I don't know that coalesce is better than isnull but coalesce is ANSI compatible where isnull is t-sql only. The two have some subtle differences in the way they work with regards to the datatype being returned.

Comment: Thank you. But what if to compare the ANSI built-in function to the T-SQL only functions. Is there any real performance difference? I know they'd work differently. But if there was a choice between two functions that give back the same result, which I'd use in the same fashion. Is there still a chance for the performance to vary?

Comment: As stated below it would require testing on a case by case basis. In general (assuming the usage is not making a query nonSARGable) there would be little to no difference.

Comment: It's better if you discuss your research explicitly in the question so that others don't have to try to repeat it in order to verify that it is correct and understand its results. Which articles? Any credible sources? Any published research, as opposed to blogs/wikis/etc.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to approach this on a case-by-case basis and do actual testing. There is no general rule, other than Microsoft tries to make the entire stack perform as well as possible. TESTING is what you need to do - we can't tell you that *always* a certain thing would be faster. That would be really bad advice.

It is important to do this testing on your actual *production* data, prefereably a copy of it. Do not rely on tests done against data sets that aren't yours. When you're talking about performance differences of functions, some very subtle things can make a big difference. Things like the size of the table, the data types involved, the indexing, and SQL Server versions, can change the result of these tests. That is why "no one has done this" for you. We can't.

Comment: Thank you. It is a shame that no one has done this. I've Googled also for the case by case testing, I have found some testing, but not in terms of SQL function vs T-SQL function (trying to achieve the same behaviour). Would be interesting to find that out. I guess people who just write in T-SQL may not even think about it?

Comment: By case to case basis Jasmine doesn't mean looking at each of the functions. Instead it would be on a query level check. What may work well in one query is not guaranteed to be the same in another. In general I wouldn't bother worrying about it much. The performance difference between ISNULL and COALESCE (with a reasonalbe number of parameters) is so negligible it is likely not even able to be measured.

Comment: See my edit - it's explaining why nobody else can do these tests for you.

Comment: Awesome, that makes a lot of sense! Thank you very much guys, good learning! :)

Comment: Well someone got me down voted is how I got thanked for asking a question that is valid to me as a learner :( and could be useful for others too. But I do thank you for your answer so I'll up vote

Comment: There are some users who down-vote for odd reasons. Like, they don't know the answer. Your question is perfectly reasonable, there's no duplicate I can find, it's written in ok English, and it's specific enough. IMO, it's a good question. I'll put in some improvements in an edit.

Comment: Aaawww thank you :3 I did ask it because I was asked by other people in my company too, who are also trying to learn SQL

Comment: @Jasmine Voting up does not mean 'Thank you!', Means this answer or question is useful. http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up. Voted you up BTW